# dropdown list Query String Parameter

Tags: asp.net

Hello everyone how you guys doing? I have a dropdown list that won't populate data values from database using sql datasource. When i use the code behind, i was able to populate the data to the dropdown list. I dont know how to pass the Query String Parameter using code behind since i am new in asp.net.

This is the code behind:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Partial Class PhotoAlbum
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim oConn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
"AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;" & _
"Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")

    Dim oCmd As New SqlCommand()
    Dim oDR As SqlDataReader

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        oConn.Open()
        oCmd.CommandText = "SELECT [CategoryID], [Name]  FROM Categories  ORDER BY [Name]"
        oCmd.Connection = oConn
        oDR = oCmd.ExecuteReader()

        Me.categories.DataSource = oDR
        Me.categories.DataTextField = "Name"
        Me.categories.DataValueField = "CategoryID"
        Me.categories.DataBind()

        oDR.Close()
        oConn.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I will like to include the following information from sqlDatasource to the codebehind:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT [CategoryID], [Name] FROM [Categories] WHERE ([UserId] = @UserId) ORDER BY [Name]"> 
    <SelectParameters> 
         <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="UserId" QueryStringField="ID"/>
```

As you can see from the code behind, i was able to add :

```
"SELECT [CategoryID], [Name]  FROM Categories  ORDER BY [Name]".
```

But i will like to add all of this:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT [CategoryID], [Name] FROM [Categories] WHERE ([UserId] = @UserId) ORDER BY [Name]"> 
        <SelectParameters>
```

Thank you guys in advance

Comment: It didnt work. Can u try it on ur own end please? Thank u

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. I haven't tested it, but the "Request.QueryString" property and the "oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue()" function are key pieces that you need to utilize.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Partial Class PhotoAlbum
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim oConn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")

    Dim oCmd As New SqlCommand()
    Dim oDR As SqlDataReader

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'TODO: probably want to make sure you have an "Id" in the query string
        If Request.QueryString("Id") Is Nothing Then
            ' TODO: handle this scenerio (no "Id" query string parameter)
        Else
            Dim userId As Integer = Nothing
            If Not Integer.TryParse(Request.QueryString("Id"), userId) Then
                ' TODO: handle this scenerio ("Id" query string parameter is not an integer)
            Else
                ' we have a good Id, use a parameterized statement to avoid SQL injection
                ' HINT: can use the "Using" statement of ensure your sql connection is disposed of when finished
                Using oConn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
                    Dim oCmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT [CategoryID], [Name] FROM [Categories] WHERE UserId = @UserId ORDER BY [Name]", oConn)
                    ' provide a value for the @userId parameter using the "parameters.addwithvalue" function
                    oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", userId)

                    oConn.Open()
                    Dim oDR As SqlDataReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader()

                    Me.categories.DataSource = oDR
                    Me.categories.DataTextField = "Name"
                    Me.categories.DataValueField = "CategoryID"
                    Me.categories.DataBind()

                    oDR.Close()
                    oConn.Close()
                End Using
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```